# How can I export part of a Flex Application to a SWF?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flash, export

I have a Flex App that allows you to dynamically build an animation. It has a UI and a display of the resulting animation, which is a custom Class extending UIComponent. Is there some way to allow users to save/export the dynamically generated Component to a SWF, for reuse in other Flash/Flex Apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily export a screenshot, but i don't think you can save a swf.
see this thread:
http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=145846

Comment: Yeah, on second thought, I don't think what I was trying to do was really necessary. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the component (or components) in a SWC design-time library or an RSL run-time library to share between applications.